# How to allow subscribers to create post of a new custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, capabilities

I am working on a plugin which adds a new custom post type and I want all users to be able to create new posts of this type. Here is what I've got at the moment:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Series', 'Post Type General Name', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Series', 'Post Type Singular Name', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Series',elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
);

// Set other options for custom post type
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'description'         => __( 'Post series', elegant_series_config()['text_domain'] ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'show_in_rest'        => true,
    'rewrite'             => array('slug' => _x('series', 'Plural', elegant_series_config()['text_domain']))
);

$administer_series = "manage_categories";

$args['capabilities'] = array(
    'edit_post'          => $administer_series,
    'read_post'          => $administer_series,
    'delete_post'        => $administer_series,
    'edit_posts'         => 'read',
    'edit_others_posts'  => $administer_series,
    'delete_posts'       => 'read',
    'publish_posts'      => $administer_series,
    'read_private_posts' => $administer_series,
    'create_posts'       => 'read',
);

// Registering your Custom Post Type
register_post_type( 'series', $args );
```

but for some reason subscribers and contributors can't add the new series. When clicking `add new` it shows a blank page with a failed ajax request which shows the following message:

```
{"code":"rest_forbidden_context","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.","data":{"status":401}}
```

I tried googling various things and play with the capabilities but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: You're creating a CPT that requires a user to have `manage_categories` capability, and Subscribers and Contributors don't have those permissions. You could either create your own capabilities and use `map_meta_cap` then add them to Subscribers and Contributors, or create your own role.

Comment: Can explain how and why `map_meta_cap` works? I read the docs but don't understand it.

Comment: Also, I want subscribers, contributors, and authors to be able to edit their own series but not other's series. Not sure how to approach that?

Comment: Actually, the way to go is the way I approached in the post I just needed to add the 'edit_post' => 'read'